# Get multiple data from checkbox using "request.POST.get"

Tags: python, django, checkbox

I tried to get multiple data from the checkbox using method below in my views.py:

```
if (((request.POST.get('data_choice ')) == ('Salary')) and ((request.POST.get('data_choice ')) and ((request.POST.get('data_choice ')) == ('Overtime')) ):
```

But the problem is the "and" condition is not working but if i use "or" condition it's work. May I know what's the problem with my code ? Is the request.POST.get can only get 1 data ?

choices.py

```
class DataChoices(models.TextChoices):
    salary = 'Salary',_('Salary')
    bonus = 'Bonus',_('Bonus')
    allowance= 'Allowance',_('Allowance')
    overtime= 'Overtime',_('Overtime')
```

models.py

```
class Data(models.Model):
    Data_choices = Data_choices
    data_choices = models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=Data_choices.choices,blank = True, null= True)
```

forms.py

```
class dataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    datachoice =  DataChoices
    data_choice =  forms.MultipleChoiceField(label=False,choices=datachoice .choices, required=True,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
        attrs= {
        "checked":"checked"
        }))
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ('__all__')
```

html

```
<form class="form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <h4 style="display:inline-block;" class="title-section">PRINT FORM</h4>
        <div class="card">
            <div  class="card-body">
                <div class="row col" >
                    <h5>Please select data to be included in the form</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-4">
                    <div class="col-lg">{{ form.data_choice |as_crispy_field }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>                     
            <div class="col " style="text-align:center;">
                <button class='btn btn-info btn-block'>Next</button>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </fieldset>     
</form>
```

views.py

```
if form.is_valid:
    data = {
    'data_choice ':request.POST.get('data_choice '),
    }
    if (((request.POST.get('data_choice ')) == ('Salary')) and ((request.POST.get('data_choice ')) == ('Bonus')) ):
        request.session['decision_data'] = data
        return redirect ('printformA')
    else:
        messages.error(request, f'Error in creating Form')
        return render(request, 'selectdata.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [**`QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

Usage:

```
data_choice = request.POST.getlist('data_choice')
```